# Проблемы с composer

Tags: laravel, composer

Пытаюсь установить Scout для laravel через composer но выдает такую ошибку
Что не так? уже все форумы облазил. Заранее спасибо
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно устанавливать [старую версию](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/scout#v2.0.2) пакета - ~2.0

Новая версия 3.0 поддерживает только Laravel 5.4

Просто допишите необходимую версию:

```
composer require laravel/scout:~2.0
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, установилось)